# Export to CSV with PHP (between selected date range)

Tags: php, mysql, csv, export-to-csv

I have export to csv using a link working correctly, though I would like to have a form where the user selects the "start date" and "end date" and everything between those dates is exported to CSV.

So far I have:
Form Submit

```
<form id="export" name="export" method="post" action="export.php">
To<input type="date" id="date1" name="date1"><br>
From<input type="date" id="date2" name="date2"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Export.php

```
<?php

$date1 = $_POST['date1'];
$date2 = $_POST['date2'];

$host = 'localhost'; // MYSQL database host adress
$db = 'chboard'; // MYSQL database name
$user = ''; // Mysql Datbase user
$pass = '"; // Mysql Datbase password
// Connect to the database
$link = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
mysql_select_db($db);

require 'exportcsv.inc.php';

$table="vacationrequests"; // this is the tablename that you want to export to csv from mysql.

exportMysqlToCsv($table);

?>
```

exportcsv.inc.php

```
<?php


function exportMysqlToCsv($table,$filename = 'export.csv')
{
$csv_terminated = "\n";
$csv_separator = ",";
$csv_enclosed = '"';
$csv_escaped = "\\";
$sql_query = "select * from $table WHERE $start >= $date1 AND $end <= $date2";

// Gets the data from the database
$result = mysql_query($sql_query);
$fields_cnt = mysql_num_fields($result);


$schema_insert = '';

for ($i = 0; $i < $fields_cnt; $i++)
{
    $l = $csv_enclosed . str_replace($csv_enclosed, $csv_escaped .       $csv_enclosed,
        stripslashes(mysql_field_name($result, $i))) . $csv_enclosed;
    $schema_insert .= $l;
    $schema_insert .= $csv_separator;
} // end for

$out = trim(substr($schema_insert, 0, -1));
$out .= $csv_terminated;

// Format the data
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $schema_insert = '';
    for ($j = 0; $j < $fields_cnt; $j++)
    {
        if ($row[$j] == '0' || $row[$j] != '')
        {

            if ($csv_enclosed == '')
            {
                $schema_insert .= $row[$j];
            } else
            {
                $schema_insert .= $csv_enclosed .
                str_replace($csv_enclosed, $csv_escaped . $csv_enclosed, $row[$j]) . $csv_enclosed;
            }
        } else
        {
            $schema_insert .= '';
        }

        if ($j < $fields_cnt - 1)
        {
            $schema_insert .= $csv_separator;
        }
    } // end for

    $out .= $schema_insert;
    $out .= $csv_terminated;
} // end while

header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Content-Length: " . strlen($out));
// Output to browser with appropriate mime type, you choose ;)
header("Content-type: text/x-csv");
//header("Content-type: text/csv");
//header("Content-type: application/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
echo $out;
exit;

}

?>
```

The output is a CSV file and in the first cell all I get is a <.  Any help in pointing me in the correct direction to get this working would be great.

Answer (score 3):

Did you try [fputcsv](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.fputcsv.php)? In case you would like to, you'll need to fetch your results and then just pass it to the function, which will write the file.